# Как поменять текст в docx не меняя форматирование

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

Мне необходимо заменить часть текста не меняя форматирование. Написал такую функцию:

```
import docx
import os

def getText(from_filename, to_filename, old_value, new_value):
    doc = docx.Document(from_filename)
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        print(paragraph.text)
        new_text = paragraph.text.replace(old_value, new_value)
        print(new_text)
        paragraph.text = new_text
    doc.save(to_filename)
```

Проблема в том, что слетает жирный шрифт и шрифт. Не могу понять как сделать тоже самое, но с сохранением форматирования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого нужно работать с свойством параграфов `runs`

Простой вариант, но **он не рабочий** (показываю **как пример**, а ниже покажу **рабочее решение**):

```
import datetime as DT

# pip install python-docx
import docx


from_filename = 'template.docx'
to_filename = 'simple.docx'


REPLACING = {
    '${title}': 'My pretty title!',
    '${datetime}': DT.datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'),
}

doc = docx.Document(from_filename)
for p in doc.paragraphs:
    for k, v in REPLACING.items():
        for run in p.runs:
            if k in run.text:
                new_text = run.text.replace(k, v)
                run.text = new_text

doc.save(to_filename)
```

Причина в том, что текст в `runs` может фрагментироваться, например у вас `{{<ключ>}}` и в каких-то случаях в `run.text` будет вся строка-шаблон, а в каких-то разбита на `{{`, `<ключ>`, `}}`.

Искал алгоритм для правильной обработки `runs` и нашел [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55733040/5909792), [решение](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/06d6f29b196f82ffcd63731ba1d76110a52e24d7/office__word__doc_docx/fill_template/save_style.py#L14):

```
import datetime as DT

# pip install python-docx
import docx


# SOURCE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55733040/5909792
def docx_replace(doc, data):
    paragraphs = list(doc.paragraphs)
    for t in doc.tables:
        for row in t.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                    paragraphs.append(paragraph)
    for p in paragraphs:
        for key, val in data.items():
            key_name = '${{{}}}'.format(key) # I'm using placeholders in the form ${PlaceholderName}
            if key_name in p.text:
                inline = p.runs
                # Replace strings and retain the same style.
                # The text to be replaced can be split over several runs so
                # search through, identify which runs need to have text replaced
                # then replace the text in those identified
                started = False
                key_index = 0
                # found_runs is a list of (inline index, index of match, length of match)
                found_runs = list()
                found_all = False
                replace_done = False
                for i in range(len(inline)):

                    # case 1: found in single run so short circuit the replace
                    if key_name in inline[i].text and not started:
                        found_runs.append((i, inline[i].text.find(key_name), len(key_name)))
                        text = inline[i].text.replace(key_name, str(val))
                        inline[i].text = text
                        replace_done = True
                        found_all = True
                        break

                    if key_name[key_index] not in inline[i].text and not started:
                        # keep looking ...
                        continue

                    # case 2: search for partial text, find first run
                    if key_name[key_index] in inline[i].text and inline[i].text[-1] in key_name and not started:
                        # check sequence
                        start_index = inline[i].text.find(key_name[key_index])
                        check_length = len(inline[i].text)
                        for text_index in range(start_index, check_length):
                            if inline[i].text[text_index] != key_name[key_index]:
                                # no match so must be false positive
                                break
                        if key_index == 0:
                            started = True
                        chars_found = check_length - start_index
                        key_index += chars_found
                        found_runs.append((i, start_index, chars_found))
                        if key_index != len(key_name):
                            continue
                        else:
                            # found all chars in key_name
                            found_all = True
                            break

                    # case 2: search for partial text, find subsequent run
                    if key_name[key_index] in inline[i].text and started and not found_all:
                        # check sequence
                        chars_found = 0
                        check_length = len(inline[i].text)
                        for text_index in range(0, check_length):
                            if inline[i].text[text_index] == key_name[key_index]:
                                key_index += 1
                                chars_found += 1
                            else:
                                break
                        # no match so must be end
                        found_runs.append((i, 0, chars_found))
                        if key_index == len(key_name):
                            found_all = True
                            break

                if found_all and not replace_done:
                    for i, item in enumerate(found_runs):
                        index, start, length = [t for t in item]
                        if i == 0:
                            text = inline[index].text.replace(inline[index].text[start:start + length], str(val))
                            inline[index].text = text
                        else:
                            text = inline[index].text.replace(inline[index].text[start:start + length], '')
                            inline[index].text = text
                # print(p.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from_filename = 'template.docx'
    to_filename = 'save_style.docx'

    REPLACING = {
        'title': 'My pretty title!',
        'date_time': DT.datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'),
    }

    doc = docx.Document(from_filename)
    docx_replace(doc, REPLACING)

    doc.save(to_filename)
```

[Файл шаблона template.docx](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/7ac07d81a97d1b63391282e74989f145d61461f7/office__word__doc_docx/fill_template/template.docx) выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат save_style.docx:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]